# Change value of one SwitchPreference depending on the value of another SwitchPreference

Tags: android

In PreferenceScreen, I can disable and enable a SwitchPreference by using `app:dependency` and  `android:disableDependentsState` but what I need is the value to be true or false and not if disabled or enabled. Is there a way that when I toggle switch1 to true, switch2 becomes false and if switch2 is true, switch1 becomes false?

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="enable_exit_cash_transaction"
    app:title="Enable Exit Cash Transaction"
    android:disableDependentsState="true"
    android:summaryOn="Exit Cash Transaction is enabled"
    android:summaryOff="Exit Cash Transaction is disabled"/>

<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    app:key="enable_entry_cash_transaction"
    app:title="Enable Entry Cash Transaction"
    app:dependency="enable_exit_cash_transaction"
    android:summaryOn="Entry Cash Transaction is enabled"
    android:summaryOff="Entry Cash Transaction is disabled"/>
```

I just extended this PreferenceFragment in my "SettingsFragment". So in this class I, literally, only have this.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences);
    }
}
```

Then I just use the navigation_graph.xml to get to this "SettingsFragment". If I need to do what I need in the code, how do I go about it? I am familiar on creating the component by using the findViewById... but I have no idea how to do this in the PreferenceScreen. How do I do the Button button = getView().findViewById(...) when I do not have I in the PreferenceScreen?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only in the code:

```
val switch1 = findPreference("enable_exit_cash_transaction") as SwitchPreferenceCompat?
switch1?.setOnPreferenceChangeListener { _, newValue ->
    switch2.isChecked = !newValue
    return@setOnPreferenceChangeListener true
}
```

Comment: Use findPreference after addPreferencesFromResource.